# Google workspace admin SDK, documentation and samples for Data Transfer API (Python)?

Tags: python, google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client

I want to transfer one user's files to another user's drive using admin SDK. I read the documentation for [data transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/reference/rest/v1/transfers/insert). To access this API with proper scopes, I need to use the python client for google. I took a look at the available [samples](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/tree/main/samples) but couldn't find anything for the **data transfer API** specifically.

```
service = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=creds)
transferService = service.transfers()
```

> AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'transfers'

and
`service = build('transfers', 'v1', credentials=creds)`
doesn't work either as apparently 'transfers' is not the name of any API. Can someone please help me getting started with the data transfer API?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service `directory_v1` indeed doesn't have a `transfers()` method.

According to the [Guides section](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/libraries) from the API mentioned, the correct python service would be `datatransfer_v1`.

Modifying the sample code provided:

```py
service = build('admin', 'datatransfer_v1', credentials=creds)
transferService = service.transfers()
```

You may want to refer to Google APIs client for python documentation for this service [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/admin_datatransfer_v1.html).